# How to remove a single element using splice() only if that element is present in the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am passing payload returned by the server to **allUsers** and want to remove the logged-in user's object from the **allUsers** array.
It is working fine when the **allUsers** length is greater than 1 but, it is removing the object even if the ids don't match if the **allUsers** contain only one object.

```
this.allUsers = response.payload.users;
this.allUsers.splice(this.allUsers.findIndex(x => x.id === sessionData.id), 1);
```

Comment: [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will return -1 if not found, but [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) accepts negative numbers. You should wrap the `splice` inside an `if (index >= 0)`.

Comment: allUsers have multiple users lets say user 1 and user 2 including the logged in user (say its user 3)? And now you need to remove the logged in user (which is user 3) from the allUsers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `filter` to get a new array with all users without the currently logged in one:

```
this.allUsers = response.payload.users.filter(x => x.id !== sessionData.id);
```

Comment: @Jackob Em: Used filter() instead of splice() and worked like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion.